# Visual Studio XAML Designer not showing correctly window's background image

Tags: visual-studio-2010, xaml

Why when I'm designing an application in Microsoft Visual Studio 2010 I get:
[image: http://i.imgur.com/Oj52lo9.png]

But when I run project I get:

[image]

How to remove this frame with "LogIn" and fix this to show real design?

**edit**

---

XAML code:

```
<Window x:Class="MemsoriaClientApplication.LogIn"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml" Title="LogIn" WindowStyle="None" ResizeMode="NoResize" WindowStartupLocation="CenterScreen" FontFamily="Verdana" FontSize="18" mc:Ignorable="d" xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" Height="189" Width="362">
<Window.Background>
    <ImageBrush ImageSource="loginInterface/bg.png"></ImageBrush>
</Window.Background>
<Grid>
    <Label Name="lbl_Title" Content="Aplikacja Memsoria.pl - Logowanie" Opacity="0" FontFamily="Tahoma" FontSize="14" Foreground="#dcdcdc" Margin="6, 5">
        <Label.RenderTransform>
            <ScaleTransform ScaleX="0" ScaleY="0"/>
        </Label.RenderTransform>
        <Label.Triggers>
            <EventTrigger RoutedEvent="Label.Loaded">
                <EventTrigger.Actions>
                    <BeginStoryboard Storyboard="{StaticResource ResourceKey=TitleAnimation}"/>
                </EventTrigger.Actions>
            </EventTrigger>
        </Label.Triggers>
    </Label>
    <Line X1="10" X2="0" Y1="30" Y2="30" Stroke="#e5e5e5" Opacity="0">
        <Line.Triggers>
            <EventTrigger RoutedEvent="Line.Loaded">
                <EventTrigger.Actions>
                    <BeginStoryboard Storyboard="{StaticResource ResourceKey=DrawLine}"/>
                </EventTrigger.Actions>
            </EventTrigger>
        </Line.Triggers>
    </Line>
    <Label Content="NAZWA KONTA:" Foreground="White" FontFamily="Tahoma" FontSize="14" Margin="7,62,-7,-62" />
    <Label Content="HASŁO:" Foreground="White" FontFamily="Tahoma" FontSize="14" Margin="7,97,-7,-62" />
    <TextBox Name="txt_login" Style="{StaticResource ResourceKey=Textbox}" Margin="108,31,-9,66" />
    <PasswordBox Margin="110,77,-7,46" Name="txt_Password" Style="{StaticResource Textbox}" />
    <Button Content="X" Style="{StaticResource ResourceKey=CloseButton}" Height="24" Name="btn_Close" Width="24" Margin="325, -155, 0, 0" Click="btn_Close_Click" />
    <Button Name="btn_LogIn" Content="Zaloguj" Style="{StaticResource ResourceKey=LoginButton}" Margin="0,119,-3,-13" Click="btn_LogIn_Click" />
</Grid>
```

Comment: Can you share the XAML code?

Comment: XAML code added. I've completed this window but still have this issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
    WindowStyle="None"
    AllowsTransparency="True"
```

Will make window appear with no border if that is what you want,

Answer (score 0):

If you use like this then your problem will be solve.

```
  WindowStyle="SingleBorderWindow"
```

Comment: But my style must be None.

Comment: For this, you have to add one custom Title bar.
Add one Border with text-block inside it before Label "lbl_Title".
Give Text = "LogIn" to the textblock